# Error using fortify function on rasters in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

After updating several of my packages yesterday, the fortify function no longer works on rasters for me. The following error is produced when I attempt to fortify a raster:

Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S4 object with class RasterLayer
Trying to fortify a raster brick/stack produces similar errors.

Anyone else having the same issue? 
Thanks!

Comment: Why not ask the author of the fortify package?  Look at the github: https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/blob/master/R/fortify.r

Answer (score 1):

I'd like to comment rather than posting an answer, because I am not sure that what worked to solve a similar issue for me will work for you, but the lacking reputation points to comment, this will have to do...

As far as I can tell, fortify within ggplot2 does not support raster input, but the package RStoolbox allows you to use fortify on raster data. If you haven't figured this issue out yet, try loading RStoolbox and see if it works.